# Laravel Blade insert JS variable in appended HTML

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am appending HTML element to my blade in a for loop. But I get his error

> Undefined array key ""

The code

```
course_count = '<?php echo count($student->courses); ?>';
for (var i = 1; i < course_count; i++) {
        const courseHtml = generate_HTML(i);
        var mydiv = document.getElementById("course_add_"+course_id);
        mydiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', courseHtml);
    }
    function generate_HTML(indexValue) {
        return `<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="course_name">Course Name</label>
                    <input id="course_name_${indexValue}" type="text" class="block" name="course_name[${indexValue}]" value="{{ $student->courses[`+indexValue+`]->course_name}}"/>
                </div>`
```

When I input the value statucally, I can view the page properly. For example

```
value="{{ $student->courses[1]->course_name}}"
```

This gives the first course name. BUt I need to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use blade directives
for example

```
@foreach($student->courses as $course)

var value = "{{$course->course_name}}"

@endofreach
```

i wish this was helpful for you

Comment: Is there any way to do it inside the JS? By appending? I need to do it inside JS,

Comment: the blade (php) code is generating your js code, so, inside your js function it cant figure out what $student->course[i] to use because the php is already rendered
so, the idea is to get the php $students into js variabl, then use the js variable